# Example 2, Sec. 11.1 in Apostol's CALCULUS, vol. 1: How to calculate this limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as 
$$f_n(x) \  \colon= \ nx (1-x^2)^n \ \mbox{ for all x } \ \in [0,1]. $$
Then $f_n(0) = 0 = f_n(1)$.

So let $0 < x < 1$.

Then what is 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)?$$

That is, what is 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} nx(1-x^2)^n$$
for a given  $0 < x < 1$?

How to calculate this limit?

And how to show rigorously that the value obtained is indeed the desired limit?

My effort:

If $0 < x < 1$, then $0 < x^2 < 1$ and hence $0 < 1-x^2 < 1$; so $0 < (1-x^2)^n < 1$. Thus $0 < nx (1-x^2)^n < nx$, but this doesn't lead us anywhere as $nx \to +\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

If $0<\alpha<1$, then $\lim_{y\to+\infty}y\cdot\alpha^y=0$

Indeed, for instance one can use the argument $$\ln(y\cdot\alpha^y)=y\ln\alpha+\ln y\to -\infty$$

**Added**: Another way to show the weaker, but sufficient, result $0<\alpha<1\Rightarrow\lim_n n\cdot\alpha^n=0$ could be: let $b_n=n\cdot\alpha^n$.

$${b_{n+1}\over b_n}={n+1\over n}\alpha\longrightarrow_n\alpha$$

So $\exists N\forall n\ge N\ \ \ {b_{n+1}\over b_n}\le{1+\alpha\over 2}<1$

Therefore definitely 
$$0\le b_n\le \left({1+\alpha\over 2}\right)^{n-N}b_N\to_n0$$

Comment: how do we know that $y \ln a + \ln y \to -\infty$ as $y \to +\infty$?

Comment: Well, the way I did it back in high school was using l'Hopital rule to calc $$\lim_{y\to+\infty}{y\ln a\over\ln y}=\lim_{y\to+\infty} {\ln a\over {1\over y}}=\text{sgn}(\ln a)\cdot(+\infty)$$ but, of course, one may argue that these tools are much harder to be proven from scratch than the actual problem. I actually do not remember if that was the case. @SaaqibMahmuud

Comment: My second approach, on the other hand, I'm $100\%$ sure it requires absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be this. We have, if $0<x<1
 $, $$\sum_{n\geq0}\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}=\frac{1}{x^{2}}
 $$ then if we derive $$\frac{-2}{1-x^{2}}\sum_{n\geq1}xn\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}=-\frac{2}{x^{3}}
 $$ hence $$\sum_{n\geq1}xn\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}=\frac{1-x^{2}}{x^{3}}
 $$ so the series is convergent and so we have $$xn\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}\longrightarrow0
 $$ as $n\rightarrow\infty
 $.

Comment: how to derive the second equality in your answer?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud $\frac{d}{dx}\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}=-2xn\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n-1}=-\frac{2}{1-x^{2}}xn\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x^{2}}=-\frac{2}{x^{3}}.$

Comment: can we justify this sort of term by term differentiation?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series